# Differences between verbs “sortir” and “partir”

Tags: vocabulaire, choix-de-mot

Both *sortir* and *partir* are the same in meaning. But what is the difference between these words in particular?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

*Sortir* and *partir* do not have the same meaning.

- [*Sortir* means *getting out of something*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/sortir) in this context. A physical object or an abstract object is needed.

For example, "*je sors de chez moi*", or "*de la fumée sort de la cheminée*", or also "*l'accélération est sortie des valeurs limites de sécurité, c'est pourquoi la fusée s'est auto-détruite*".

When no object is specified *from here*, *from where the subject is currently* should be assumed: "*je sors. (d'ici)*" or "*attention, quand je dévisserai ce bouchon, du liquide va sortir (du réservoir)*".

- [*Partir* means *to leave a place*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/partir), or an entity, in this context. A destination may be specified.

For example, "*je pars deux semaines en Espagne cet été*", or "*Jean a démissionné, il est parti chez un concurrent*", or also "*Stéphanie est partie ? (de cette réunion)*".

- In certain cases, this is subtle:

> *Stéphanie est partie ?* suggests she left the party, or the meeting, for good

while

> *Stéphanie est sortie ?* suggests this is temporary: she will be back in a while

Comment: Another important distinction is that sortir is also used when talking about going out with someone on a date. "*Je sors avec cette fille ce soir*"

Comment: 1) Both sortir and partir (in the meaning of "to leave") must have an origin point. If it is not specified, "here" is implicitly assumed. 2) A destination may also be specified with sortir , eg. "je sors dans la rue". You speak like if these two characteristics were exclusive of only one of those verbs.

Comment: @AlanEvangelista 1) is wrong actually. "Qu'a-t-elle fait ensuite ? Elle est sortie.". Not from "here", but from where she was. She left the room or the building or anything the context implies. This would have worked with partir too:  "Qu'a-t-elle fait ensuite ? Elle est partie.". 2) is right, a destination may be specified with sortir. The answer above doesn't say it cannot.

Answer (score 1):

*Sortir* is used when the subject leaves a place.

> L'oiseau *est sorti* de son oeuf.

On the contrary, *partir* is generally used when it implies the destination.

> Il *est parti* en France pour l'été.

We can use *partir* without a destination. In that case, it will mean that he left for a long moment.

Answer (score 0):

Les deux verbes n'ont pas le même sens: ''Sortir'' c'est statique, changer de décor encombrant, de coquille, de cachette, se défaire, se libérer d'embarras, tandis que ''partir'' c'est se déplacer à quelque part pour de bon, le plus souvent sans revenir au lieu de départ.

Comment: Que signifie "changer de décor encombrant" ? D'autres expressions sont curieuses "se défaire", "se libérer d'embarras", "se déplacer à quelque part".

Answer (score -1):

In English, partir is to *depart* (or leave). Sortir is to *sortie*, (or go out of). You can go out of something (e.g. a house) without leaving the general vicinity.

Comment: "Sortir is to sortie" that doesn't actually help translate. "Sortie" is not an English word.